# Variable with conditionals

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, gekko

I'm working in a problem of optimization with [Gekko](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/) and I have a complex equation with sums and many variables, but it is not a problem. The main difficulty is to write a variable that involves conditionals in its calculation, suppose this variable is called "X" and is calculated as mentioned in [EQUATION](https://latex.codecogs.com/png.image?%5Cinline&space;%5Cdpi%7B150%7D&space;X=%5Cleft%5C%7B%5Cbegin%7Bmatrix%7D0&,&10%3C%5Cfrac%7Ba%7D%7Bb%7D%5C%5Ca-b&,&%5Cfrac%7Ba%7D%7Bb%7D%3C10%3Cab%5C%5C1&,&10%5Cgeq&space;ab%5C%5C%5Cend%7Bmatrix%7D%5Cright.), how could I implement this?

[image: Equation]

I've read [Conditional Statements with Gekko](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/ConditionalStatements), but I'm still in doubt.

Comment: I don't know anything about `Gekko`, but from the document you linked, have you tried writing something using `if2()` or `if3()`?  Perhaps if you added what you tried it would give others who might actually know Gekko a jump start in helping you.

Comment: @JonSG That's the point, [ConditionalStatementsWithGekko](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/ConditionalStatements) shows an example of using `if2` and `if3`, but I don't know how to adapt it in my case. The examples have two conditionals, but I have three... I don't know if it's possible to solve my problem with Gekko and that's why I tried to leave the question more open. Tks.

Comment: @JohnHedengren All inequalities are correct. Only the value `a - b` is not exactly what I need, but a representation to exemplify the value is calculated from a and b.

Comment: I was just thinking through the combinations. What if a/b>10 and a*b<=10 such as with a=20 and b=0.01? Would the result be X=0 or X=1?

Comment: @JohnHedengren The honest answer is I don't know. Originally `10` is not a constant, but a value calculated from physical observations. Could this impact the answer? (I don't think so) I'm focused on the technical solution, but your question is also relevant. If you could give some guidance, I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logical constraints can be implemented with `m.if3()` with binary switching variables (or `m.if2()` MPCC form).

```py
# conditionals
c1 = m.if3(a/b-10,1,0) # check if a/b>10
c2 = m.if3(10-a*b,1,0) # check if a*b<=10
```

These switching variables can then be used to calculate `X`.

```py
# output
# when c1=0 (a/b>10), X=0
# when c1=1 (a/b<10) and c2=1 (a*b>10), X=a-b
# when c1=1 (a/b<10) and c2=0 (a*b<10), X=1
X = m.Var()
m.Equation(X==c1*c2*(a-b) + c1*(1-c2)*(1))
```

[image: results]

Here is a complete script for this simple test case in simulation where the value of `a` is a range of values.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
a = m.Param([0.5,1,2,3,4,6,8,12,15,20,30,40,50])
b = 2
d = m.Intermediate(a/b); e=m.Intermediate(a*b)
# conditionals
c1 = m.if3(a/b-10,1,0) # check if a/b>10
c2 = m.if3(10-a*b,1,0) # check if a*b<=10
# output
# when c1=0 (a/b>10), X=0
# when c1=1 (a/b<10) and c2=1 (a*b>10), X=a-b
# when c1=1 (a/b<10) and c2=0 (a*b<10), X=1
X = m.Var()
m.Equation(X==c1*c2*(a-b) + c1*(1-c2)*(1))

# solve
m.options.IMODE=2
m.solve(disp=True)

print(a.value)
print(X.value)

# generate plot of results
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.subplot(4,1,1)
plt.plot(a.value,X.value,'b-o',label='X')
plt.legend(); plt.grid()
plt.subplot(4,1,2)
plt.plot(a.value,d.value,'k-o',label='a/b')
plt.plot([0.5,50],[10,10],'k--')
plt.legend(); plt.grid()
plt.subplot(4,1,3)
plt.plot(a.value,e.value,'r-o',label='a*b')
plt.plot([0.5,50],[10,10],'r--')
plt.legend(); plt.grid()
plt.subplot(4,1,4)
plt.plot(a.value,c1.value,'k:x',label='c1 (a/b<10)')
plt.plot(a.value,c2.value,'r:x',label='c2 (a*b<10)')
plt.legend(); plt.grid(); plt.xlabel('a')
plt.tight_layout(); plt.savefig('results.png',dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

This can now be used in optimization to maximize, minimize, or reach a target value for `X` such as where the value of `a` is adjusted to maximize `X`:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
a = m.Var(lb=0,ub=100)
b = 2
d = m.Intermediate(a/b); e=m.Intermediate(a*b)
# conditionals
c1 = m.if3(a/b-10,1,0) # check if a/b>10
c2 = m.if3(10-a*b,1,0) # check if a*b<=10
# output
# when c1=0 (a/b>10), X=0
# when c1=1 (a/b<10) and c2=1 (a*b>10), X=a-b
# when c1=1 (a/b<10) and c2=0 (a*b<10), X=1
X = m.Var()
m.Equation(X==c1*c2*(a-b) + c1*(1-c2)*(1))
m.Maximize(X)

# solve
m.options.IMODE=3
m.solve(disp=True)

print(f'a={a.value[0]}')
print(f'X={X.value[0]}')
```

This gives the correct solution of:

```
a=20.0
X=18.0
```

Note that `>` and `>=` are equivalent for numerical optimization in Gekko. The solution of `a=20.0` is at the switching condition between `X=a-b` and `X=0`. The simulation result shows `X=0` at `a=20` while the optimization result shows `X=18` at `a=20`. There are default solver tolerances (`m.options.RTOL` for equations and `m.options.RTOL` for objective) that allow solutions within `1e-6` of the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
if 10<a/b:
  x=0
elif a/b<10 and 10<a*b:
  x=a*b
else:
  x=1
```

Comment: No. As explained in [ConditionalStatements](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/ConditionalStatements), expressing the condition as a typical if, else construct in Python is a common error with conditional statements.

Gekko has the if2 and if3 functions, but I still don't see how to write "X" using them.

Tks!

Comment: @stwrt You should make it *very clear* in your question that you are trying to do that in the context of Gekko, not just by adding this tag and giving a link with a not-so-explicit about that name.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I appreciate your recommendations and tried to make the question clearer.